# Should a swift method return a protocol type or a concrete type?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, module, protocols

On a current project we are trying to use Protocols instead of concrete definitions to define types so that they can be used in the main app and are easy to unit test using protocol doubles. e.g.

```
protocol UserProtocol {
    var firstName: String { get }
    var lastName: String { get }
    var userName: String { get }
    // ... plenty of other properties as the app has grown
}
```

Then we have created separate modules for the app which are concerned with a subset of these properties in each module. For example a hypothetical network manager and user settings manager will be concerned with a different subset of properties defined in separate protocols to help with local reasoning and to create simpler test doubles for this modules.

```
// For User settings
protocol UserSettingType {
    var firstName: String { get }
    var lastName: String { get }
    var notificationTypes: [String] { get }
    var userName: String { get } // Common to both
}
```

and

```
// For the Network manager
protocol NetworkUserType {
    var userName: String { get } // Common to both
    var userUUID: String { get 
    var password: String { get }
    var deviceToken: String? { get }
}
```

I would like to keep the User settings and Network manager separated from the rest of the app as much possible so they can be abstracted with a more plugin type architecture. Therefore I wanted to be able to apply these smaller protocols retroactively to the UserProtocol but Swift won't allow it. e.g..

```
extension UserProtocol: UserSettingType { } // Extension of protocol 'UserProtocol' cannot have an inheritance clause.
```

but by implementing a concrete type with conformance to `UserProtocol` that is fine.

```
struct User: UserProtocol {
    ...
} 
extension User: UserSettingType { } // works fine
```

My initial reaction is that this is an unnecessary limitation of Swift and it would better to be able to provide that flexibility but then I've thought more about the use cases.

1. I cannot pass around actual `UserProtocol` instances but rather they would always be specific instances of the `UserProtocol` such as a `class`, `struct` or `enum`.
2. They would only come from an initialiser or the return type from a method which would always be a specific type. It might happen to conform to the `UserProtocol` but there is going to be more specific information about the type such as whether it is a reference or value type. So therefore there is no actual flexibility here but only the loss of information.
3. The only place I would want the flexibility to substitute an instance conforming to a protocol rather than a concrete type is as the input parameter to a method (mostly for unit tests).

With this in mind I have come to a conclusion that I should have input to methods be protocols for the flexibility of test instance creation and the return instances from methods as concrete types.

```
func retrieveAUser() -> User { //concrete return type
    ...
}

func userSettingsSampleFunction(user: UserSettingType) { // Protocol as input
    ...
}
```

I have had feedback that we should use protocols for input and output to allow for flexibility but I cannot see the benefits of this. 
I would be very interested to here some thoughts on which way is the best.
Should input parameters and return types be Protocol types, should I return concrete types or is there a better alternative?

Please note I have not mentioned Generics since the use case is mainly concerned with enabling convenient testing but if may worth looking at if anyone has any ideas.

Many thanks

Comment: A non-concrete obviously won't work on a protocol metatype but how about creating a type constrained method i.e: func test<T : UserProtocol >(params...) -> T is that something you are trying to achieve ? Because using this method is by inferring the type i.e: let object : UserConcrete = instance.test....